# Go to settings screen

Tags: android, android-settings

I want to open the Settings-> Sound & Display-> Phone Ringtones screen from my application. How can I do that?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Depending on your needs, there are a couple of alternatives to bring up the 'Ringtones' settings screen from your application.

If you want to bring up the actual preferences screen that is usually available through system settings -- letting your user modify the phone's universal ringtone settings through your application -- you can use the `ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS` constant from the  `android.provider.Settings` class to create a new Intent to start the sound settings activity.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS), 0);
```

If you want to select a custom ringtone to use in your application you need to add a `RingtonePreference` in your `preferences.xml` definition file, like this:

```
<RingtonePreference
  android:key="alerts_ringtone"
  android:title="Select ringtone" 
  android:showDefault="true"
  android:showSilent="true"
  android:ringtoneType=""
/>
```

You'll be able to get the URI to the selected preference in the application's default `SharedPreferences` using `alerts_ringtone` as the key.

*The latter technique uses the `PreferenceActivity` class to host the preference options. I won't describe that in detail here, as the Android documentation has a [good writeup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) and some sample code.*

Comment: Thanks. I want to open the Preferences screen. So will executing the Intent statement let the user set a ringtone or as soon as the user selects a ringtone it will come back to the app and the app will have to set it?

Comment: Executing the Intent statement will let the user set the ringtone -- your app won't have to do anything to handle it separately.

Comment: Note as per 2nd answer there is a mistake in first code fragment, a closing bracket is needed just after the first parameter in the Intent constructor. Would just edit but needs to be over 6 chars :)

Answer (score 7):

This is an alternate solution for the problem. I am also working in the same task but the above code does not work for me. I have changed the code to

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS), 0);
```

and it now works.

Comment: This doesnt work for Nougat, please help. app not opening