# How to start an activity which display "Sound & Display " screen

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new in android development. I am making an application using intent which to show a sound and display settings screen. I used the following code to have it.

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS);
       this.startActivityForResult(viewIntent,0);
```

But it doesnt work. It give me force close the application.

If anyone help me about this..

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623225/android-go-to-settings-screen . Btw improve ur AR a bit

Comment: With an AR of 0% I doubt paul knows what AR is :)

Answer (score 1):

full solution:

```
Intent aa = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(aa,0);
```