# Device Admin Settings Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to have a shortcut to the device admin settings page on my `Widget`.

I have looked at the `AndroidManifest.xml` (for the standard Android Settings App) for the `Intent` string, but it doesn't seem to be there, any ideas where it would be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623225/android-go-to-settings-screen) you can launch an `Intent` with any string from the `android.provider.Settings` class, with different ones for different things. The list of available strings is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html).

Comment: Thanks Martin, I have been using that list, but it doesn't seem to be exhaustive.  I have been able to find quite a few more in the Android Settings App's AndroidManifest.xml, but for DeviceAdminSettings it just lists the generic: - <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />.  I thought there might have been a bigger list somewhere.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you find the appropriate Intent for Device Admin Ash? If so please share.