# Open a specific setting view through an url in Android

Tags: android, settings, uri

I want to open the setting view for enabling Unknown Sources from the **web browser**. I know that it is possible to access for example a specific app in Android Market by "http://market.android.com/details?id=". Now I want to use that kind of url to open the settings view, something like "http://settings.android.com/?view=applications".

Has anyone tryied something like this?

Comment: I suggest you look in the logcat what intent is used when you open a particular settings page.

Comment: also, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623225/android-go-to-settings-screen

Comment: I see the intents and think it could be a way to try to create an intent from the web browser. So the questions is how you do that, I found this answer but I do not get it to work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5651246/666148