# How can I call the date time settings screen from my android application?

Tags: android, settings, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm developing an application for mobiles and tables using **Android 2.3.**

In my application, I want the user able to modify device's date, time values. I know that it is not possible via android applications.

I planned to access the date/time settings screen from  my application. From that screen user can change the settings.

Please give your ideas how to access or go to the date time settings screen from android application.

All are welcome to give your ideas.

Comment: check it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623225/android-go-to-settings-screen

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try using this code. It opens the date and time setting screen .

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Comment: above code doesnt work for api level 24 nougat devices.pls help